# how to sum value children parent array sequently

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, tree, parent

i have this kind of tree array,
here is the actual data of my array
https://pastebin.com/xtfpyKiE

there is id,parent_id, and value on each item,

```
id:1,
name:A,
value:0
   |
   ----id:2
       parent:1,
       name:B,
       value : 10
         |
         ------id:3,
               parent:2,
               name :C,
               value : 12
                  |
                   ------id:4,
                         parent:3,
                         name :D,
                         value : 14
```

how to sum the value by parent id,
from the bottom child to the top parent,

so i can get the value of A : 36,
value of B : 36,
value of C : 26,

thank you,

Comment: your "ascii picture" doesn't show how the "link" from parent to child is implemented (child to parent, yes, butwhat does the | and ------ represent?) there's also no evidence of an array (or "tree array") - it actually looks more like a linked list, without any forward links - so ... it's kinda useless information really

Comment: This would be more convenient to answer if you showed the data using standard JS array and object literal syntax (because it would make the parent-child link mechanism clearer, and then we could copy the data into our answers for use in demos). @JaromandaX - Doesn't the `parent` attribute (where present) specify the `id` of each element's parent? My guess is it's a flat array of objects linked only by data values, not by object references (but I'm not going to try to answer based just on that guess).

Comment: hi im sorry, i think it would be easier to understand to use that, let me edit my question and attach my actual array on it, here is the actual data https://pastebin.com/xtfpyKiE

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring assignment to get nested properties of object and assign retrieved values to an array in sequence. Use a loop to `.splice()` two elements at a time from array to create object having `A:36,B:36,C:26` pairs, push object back to array.

```js
const data = {id:1, name:"A", value:0
             , parent:{id:2, name: "B", value: 10
               , parent:{id:3, name: "C", value: 12
                 , parent:{id:4, name: "D", value: 14}
                 }
               }
             };

let res = [];

({name:res[res.length], value:res[res.length]
, parent:{
    name:res[res.length], value:res[res.length]
    , parent:{
        name:res[res.length], value:res[res.length]
        , parent:{
            name:res[res.length], value:res[res.length]}}}} = data);

let k = res.length / 2;

while (res.length > k) {
  let [key, prop] = res.splice(0, 2);
  res.push({[key]:prop 
                  + (res[1] && !isNaN(res[1]) && res[1] || 0) 
                  + (res[3] && !isNaN(res[3]) && res[3] || 0) 
                  + (res[5] && !isNaN(res[5]) && res[5] || 0)
      });
}

// A : 36, value of B : 36, value of C : 26

console.log(res)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, i have edited my question and add my actual array data on it, could you please give me a snippet code based on that ?